# Java 8 - Spring 5/WebSockets: struggling with websockets in microservice architecture

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, websocket, spring-websocket

I was trying implement a websocket in one of my microservices, I follow some tutorials and all works fine, so I tried implement the same code in my project just to test the handshake between client and server, but I couldn't do it I think that could be a problem with my reverse proxy or docker-compose configuration, but I'm not sure because the server receive the request.

1. Is the reverse proxy functioning correctly?
2. What does that unusual exception mean? I don't have information about where the error in the code could be.
3. Am I omitting some configuration in Spring or in my Docker Compose? Could there be an issue with the ports?

This is my **WebSocketConfig.kt**

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class WebSocketConfig: WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    override fun configureMessageBroker(config: MessageBrokerRegistry) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic")
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
    }

    override fun registerStompEndpoints(registry: StompEndpointRegistry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat")
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS()
        registry.addEndpoint("/chatwithbots")
        registry.addEndpoint("/chatwithbots").withSockJS()
    }
}
```

This is my **WsController.kt**

```kotlin
@Controller
class WsController { 
   ... 
   @MessageMapping("/chat")
   @SendTo("/topic/messages")
   @Throws( Exception::class ) 
   fun send(message: Message): OutputMessage { 
       val time = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(Date())
       return OutputMessage(message.from, message.text, time)
    } 
    ... 
}
```

This is my **docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.3
    container_name: traefik
    command:
      - --log.level=INFO
      - --accesslog=true
      - --ping=true
      - --ping.entryPoint=http
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      - --entryPoints.http.forwardedHeaders.insecure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8000:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

  ws_microservice:
    build: ./ws_microservice
    image: registry.gitlab.com/<path>/ws_microservice
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.ws_microservice.rule=PathPrefix(`/ws_microservice`)
      - traefik.http.routers.ws_microservice.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.services.ws_microservice.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
    volumes:
      - ./ws_microservice/build/out/BOOT-INF/classes:/app
      - ./ws_microservice/build/out/BOOT-INF/lib:/app/lib
      - ./ws_microservice/build/out/META-INF:/app/META-INF
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1G
          cpus: "0.5"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
      - traefik
    tty: true
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5120:5005"
      - "5121:8080"

  rabbitmq:
    #build: ./rabbitmq
    image: registry.gitlab.com/<path>/rabbitmq
    container_name: rabbitmq
    hostname: rabbitmq-local
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.rabbitmq.rule=PathPrefix(`/rabbitmq`)
      - traefik.http.routers.rabbitmq.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.services.rabbitmq.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 500M
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
      - "8080:8080"

  postgres:
    image: postgis/postgis:12-3.3
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - postgres_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./postgres/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    shm_size: '256MB'

volumes:
  postgres_volume:

networks:
  default:
    name: local_network
```

I use a ws postman client ws://localhost:5121/ws_microservice/chat

Server logs

```bash
INFO [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]

WARN [nio-8080-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "chat"]
```

Postman response

```
Error: Unexpected server response: 400
Handshake Details
Request URL: http://localhost:5121/ws_microservice/chat
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 400 
Request Headers
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: h7ua6ck7O2lj+3H7ktdi/w==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Authorization: <token>
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Host: localhost:5121
Response Headers
Vary
0: Origin
1: Access-Control-Request-Method
2: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 12 Jan 2024 14:12:16 GMT
Connection: close
```

I experimented with different port mappings, such as mapping to port 80, but the server didn't log anything; it only logged when I mapped ports to 8080.

I attempted to search for more information in the Traefik dashboard, but I found nothing useful.

I tried different URLs, even without using "ws_microservice" in the path. However, in my application.properties, I have:

```bash
server.servlet.context-path=/ws_microservice
server.tomcat.redirect-context-root=false
```

I believe I should use this context path.

I ran a simple project using WebSockets, and it works fine with the same configuration, using localhost:8080. Therefore, I suspect there might be an error within my microservices architecture.

I understand that Traefik 2 supports WebSockets by default